# Running Qt libraries from Xcode 4

Tags: c++, qt, xcode4

It is well known that the current version of Qt doesn't allow to convert the project to xcode4 project http://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-17247. Anyways, at least in theory, it should be possible to compile something in xcode by linking the proper Qt libraries (either dynamic or static), right?

I have taken one Qt 4.7.4 example: "Hello world" and copy/paste the source code into my main. I included the proper headers `/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/473/gcc/include/**`. Then I added the three frameworks QtScript, QtCore, QtGui. The linker still gives me errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "qInitResources_helloscript()", referenced from:
  _main in main.o
  ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

I also tried to link with all the libraries in `/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/473/gcc/include/` but still no luck. Also tried with other Qt creator examples, but I get all other sorts of linker errors.